# Why am I getting this Python Database Connectivity Error?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

> Error:tns:listener was not given the service_name in connect_data

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/hr@localhost')
if  con!= None:
    print('Connection established successfully')
    print('Version:',con.version)
else:
    print('Connection not established')
con.close()
```

Comment: Could you paste the whole error trackback please? It will make finding a solution a lot easier.

Comment: cx_oracle.DatabaseError ora-12504 tns:listener was not given the service_name in connect_data

Answer (score 0):

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/hr@localhost:1521/orcl')
if  con!= None:
    print('Connection established successfully')
    print('Version:',con.version)
else:
    print('Connection not established')
con.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.